# Adjusting numbers in a list based on constraints

Tags: list, constraints, histogram, distribution

I have a list of numbers and confidences in this numbers, for ex.

`[(24, 0.2), (23, 0.3), (21, 0.3), (19, 0.1), (18, 0.15), (18, 0.2), (17, 0.3), (13, 0.3), (12, 0.2), (12, 0.3), (11, 0.2), (11, 0.1), (10, 0.2), (7, 0.3), (5, 0.3)]`.

I also have bins

`[5, 12], [12, 15], [15, 20], [20, 25]`

and proportions related to each of these bins for ex.,

`0.25, 0.4, 0.1, 0.25`

I need to adjust the numbers taking into account their confidence so that bin counts align with proportions.

I am not sure how to approach this. Maybe this is more relevant for Statistics?

Thank you.